# .NET 6 replace parameter checks with ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull();

Tags: c#, upgrade, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading our application to .NET 6 from .NET 3.1 Core and trying to use the new `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull();`

But in our code, we do not only check for null but also for other things.

```cs
if (anyParam == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(anyParam));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringParam))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(stringParam));
}

if (intParam <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(intParam ));
}

if (listParam.Count == 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(listParam));
}
```

Since Rule [CA2208](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2208) now wants to change all ArgumentException lines, which we have a lot of, this would be a lot of work.

I want to know is it only safe to replace pure null checks like in the first example, or what is it all checking for in case of different parameter types. Couldn't find the proper documentation.

I would like to replace as much as I can with:

```cs
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(anyParam);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mixing up two completely unrelated issues here:

The first one is replacing *your very first check* with `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull`. Sure, that's a good idea to do! Starting with .NET 7, you will also be able to replace your second check with [`ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception.throwifnullorempty?view=net-7.0).

The second issue is that your second, third and fourth checks are broken and should be fixed (this is what [CA2208](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2208) is about): The first parameter of `ArgumentNullException` is `paramName`, but the first parameter of `ArgumentException` is **not** `paramName`, it's `message`.

For example, your line

```
if (intParam <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(intParam));
}
```

should actually be:

```
if (intParam <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(intParam) + " must be a positive integer.");
}
```

(Or, optionally:)

```
if (intParam <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(intParam) + " must be a positive integer.", 
                                nameof(intParam));
}
```

---

As suggested in the comments, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` might be an even better option for this particular check. Note though, that, contrary to `ArgumentException`'s constructor, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (like `ArgumentNullException`) takes the parameter name *first* and *then* (optionally) the message. I.e., you can use either

```
if (intParam <= 0)
{
    // yield a generic "out of range" exception message
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(intParam));
}
```

or

```
if (intParam <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(intParam),
        nameof(intParam) + " must be a positive integer.");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for the int checks.

Comment: `ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty` don't exist in .NET 6. It's available from .NET 7.

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't a burden to handle so many exceptions on upper layers? Local handlers, global handlers, retries, then retries at retries, and what if we don't see the forest by the trees? Meaning we fix exception 1 but after the fix exception 2 happens.

Comment: Wouldn't be better beside constructors (where null argument exception is accepted), to use model state inside service layer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs or maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=net-6.0 if we want to throw an exception to cover all failed validations?

Comment: @SilentTremor `isn't a burden to handle so many exceptions on upper layers` There's no exception *handling* in any of the code posted in the question or the answer. And let's suppose we don't throw an exception in the method guards. What then? We just get a `NullReferenceException` a little later? Or worse, an incorrect result from a calculation which doesn't throw an exception at all?

Comment: It just a question, handler or no handler, ask remains, isn't exception used as a expected behavior dangerous and hard to maintain and there's the trap of if exception is of type x do that, but what if the type x resulted from another place, not from where usually is expected to happen, what then?

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry, are 2 comments (second related to first), I not saying to remove arguments validation, but instead of an exception throwing to use a different pattern to handle arguments/model validation

Comment: ok so I'll replace only the null checks and for other occurences I'll use the correct syntax for ArgumentException. Also found there's a fix available from the rule which I can apply to the whole Solution

Comment: @SilentTremor Ah OK, I see what you mean. I guess that depends on where the methods being validated are - are they low-level, or are they in the business model etc.

Comment: @MatthewWatson there in the low level data handler. So no handling there. Only throwing

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Good idea with ArgumentOutOfRange exception. I've added a note.